# Showing messages on Public faced login page even before login into the saleforce where messages are sitting on the custom object?

Tags: apex, visualforce, rest-api

I am rephrasing my question.

I have login page for Customer Portal Logn. 
I need to show some messages in the Login page based on the Users Selected language from the drop down, the issue here is all the messages are in a salesforce object and I need to show the messages even before login, I know this sounds a bit weird with out login accessing to the salesforce custom object is not possible. But I felt there might be some other way where some one has did this. Please shower your thoughts.

Thanks,
Suri.

Comment: I suggest you move the messages to some JSON - you can use the language code as a field name in the structure - that you store in a public static resource and reference that from your Angular code. Otherwise you are fighting the security mechanisms provided on custom objects. If you want to keep your messages custom object you can write Apex code to build the JSON from that and use the metadata API to update the static resource - example of something similar [here](https://force201.wordpress.com/2015/06/01/picklist-values-by-record-type-for-angularjs-ui/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a Customer Portal User Login Page I can do the query on the Custom object and fetch the messages based on the language User selected by a Guest profile Customer Portal User.